# Use case and meaning of “lest” in sentences

Tags: meaning, old-english, language-evolution

What is the exact meaning of *lest?* [Oxford Learner's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/lest) defines it: "in order to prevent something from happening", and its Origin is "Old English thȳ lǣs the ‘whereby less that’, later the læste".

My confusion is because *lest* is derived from old English [(Etymonline)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lest) which means "less that", so does *lest* mean to "absolutely avoid things out of fear" or  "minimise the effect", or both?

Comment: Where did you get "less that" from? OED doesn't have that. Which "Oxford" are you quoting? Your definition is not in OED either. Please [edit] your question to include links, or at least the relevant Oxford title.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I have Edit the Question

Comment: *What is the exact meaning of **lest***? -- In English, there are very few "exact meanings" as that implies a true synonym, which are exceedingly rare. The meaning, or at least the nuance, of a word is strongly influenced by context and tone.

Comment: "Lest" isn't quite obsolete/archaic, but it's not something you'd hear in casual speech. It has a few specific usages in modern literary and legal English which you should easily get from a dictionary (probably not Oxford Learners, which is more focused on colloquial English, but try Merriam Webster)

Answer (score 2):

English has undergone a huge transformation in a thousand years, to the extent that it's no longer the same language, albeit with recognisable vestiges of Old English. *Lest* is one such vestige.

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107487) (probably paywalled) has

> Old English phrase *þý lǽs þe,* lit. ‘whereby less’ = Latin *quōminus* (*þý* instrumental of the demonstrative and relative pronoun + *lǽs* "less" *adj.* + *þe* relative particle). In Middle English the first word of the phrase was dropped, and *les þe* became *les te* in accordance with the general rule that *þ* after *s* changed into *t.*

There are several citations, the earliest of which is John 5:14 (my emphasis) —

> c1000   *West Saxon Gospels: John* (Corpus Cambr.) v. 14   Ne synga þu **þe-læs þe** þe on sumon þingon wyrs getide.
>
> Do not sin, lest something worse befall you.

I **think** that this meaning of *less* is now obsolete, and related to what the OED has as

> †**A.1.f.** With anticipatory *it* and infinitive as complement. Of an action: not so great, worthy, or excellent. *Obsolete.*

...which basically means "worse" — *lest* is introducing a worse alternative.

Because the language has changed so much, it's not possible to directly "translate" every OE instrumental and particle or even adjective into modern English. All one can do is to see where the thread runs from *lǽs* "less=worse" to the modern *lest*.